# I am studying C++, Can't I access reference by using pointer? (having an example)

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Ok I have used C for 3 years.
My major is embedded system Engineering
I have had an interest in image processing just a few days ago.
So I am studying C++.

I want to change last character when I use copy constructor.
like these -> Cannon1 Cannon2 Cannon3  (Cannon is just name)
So I used pointer with While as I do in C.

```
Photon_Cannon::Photon_Cannon(int x, int y, char *cannon_name)
{
    int i = 0;
    hp = shield = 100;
    coord_x = x;
    coord_y = y;
    damage = 20;
    name = new char[strlen(cannon_name) + 1];
    strcpy(name, cannon_name);
}
```

this is original code (this works normally)

and I attached some codes end of the section of copy constructor.

```
while (*name!=NULL) {
        name++;
    }
    *name+=1;
```

but it doesn't work! :(

help me...

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work"? *How* doesn't it work? Do you get build errors? Crashes? Unexpected results? Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: A few other notes: `NULL` is used for null *pointers* and not the string null terminator (which is either plain `0` or `'\0'`). It *usually* works with `NULL` because it's usually a macro defined as `0`, but it's more a thing to make readers of the code understand it. Also, when you do `name++` you modify the pointer you have, so that you lose the original pointer and can't use it with `delete[]`. Lastly, `*name += 1` will modify the string terminator, so the string is no longer terminated (after the loop, `name` will point at the terminator).

Comment: I understand that you come from a `C` background, but this is `C++`. Use `std::string` instead of c string functions like `strlen`. This will take care of another problem you have: in `C++` you should almost never use explicit `new`

Comment: If `NULL` is defined as `(void*)0` as in C, you are comparing char against pointer (`*name != NULL`). Should rather be `*name != 0` or simply `while(*name)`. If you really compare pointers, prefer `nullptr` keyword instead of NULL macro...

Comment: Use std::string!

Comment: Not related to your question, just a helpful link I think you'll be glad to have in your bookmarks: http://cppreference.com/

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `std::string` instead of `char*`.

```
Photon_Cannon::Photon_Cannon(int x, int y, const std::string& cannon_name)
```

Change member variable `name` to `std::string` aswell, then you can easily assign string's like

```
name = cannon_name;
```

And then change last character

```
name[name.length() - 1] = '2';
```

Or

```
    name.pop_back();
    name += "2";
```

Don't forget to include string.

Or with char*

```
name[strlen(name) - 1] = '2';
```

Dont forget to check size of array/string, `name.length() > 0)`, (int)strlen(name) > 1, ...

I would recommend you to read some c++ tutorial's like
[C++ strings](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).

Iam new on stackoverflow, so i hope it helped you :).

Comment: Filip Kočica and others thank you! today is my first time to study C++! I will check the site :)

Comment: Please don't teach passing `std::string` by copy if you don't `std::move` it afterwards. The normal way to pass it around is by const reference.

Comment: I'm really glad to have helped you. I wish a lot of fun while studying C++. :)

Comment: @emlay In general, I'm absolutely with you, in the specific case, we'd need a copy internally anyway, so we *could* make one here immediately (parameter) and skip the local (`name`) duplicate for...

Comment: Of course, i usually use const and reference, but i forgot today :/ Thank you guys for your comments.

Comment: You cannot assign a string to a character (`name[x]  = ""`, needs to be `name[x] = '2'`). I'd prefer `name += '2'` for the second case, too, if we just want to append a single character. Sure not *much* difference, but still it is more efficient...

Comment: Yes your point is right "2" isn't just '2', but "2\0" so it cannot be assigned to one character, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not intended as answer, just as a side note to Filip's already given answer (and the comments there):

```
void f(std::string const& s)
```

This is the *usual* way to pass std::string objects, because it avoids creating unnecessary copies of (costing runtime and memory). If you actually want to modify the string (changes will be visible to the string object passed to `f`), leave away the const modifier.

Now here we have a special case:

```
void f(std::string const& s)
{
    std::string ss(s); // creates a COPY!

    // modify the copy ss...
}
```

Obviously, the copy is to be modified, but changes shall not be visible to the original string object passed to. If we don't need access to the original string any more (`s`), ***then*** and ***only*** then, it makes sense to pass the string by value:

```
void f(std::string /*const&*/ s) // creates the COPY already when passing
{
    /* std::string ss(s); // creates a COPY! */ // <- don't need it any more

    // modify the COPY s now...
}
```

Side note: Really leaving the const reference as comment as above (`/*const&*/`) would express (and should suffice for) that passing by value was done *intentionally*...